# Modal window blocks command perform

Tags: c#, wpf, button, click, command

I am doing small wpf MVVM aplication and I have (maybe) quite simple problem. I have button, that performs opening of a new window by button_click. I use just this code in my Button_click method:

```
Winow1 w = new Window1() { Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow, };
w.DataContext = this.DataContext;
w.ShowDialog();
```

But this Button is also binded to the command, but click is performed first and command is blocked by modal window and is performed after I close the window.

I need this command to be performed before click or simultaneously with the click. Do you know any way of doing this?

I can post some more code if needed.

**EDIT**
This command only takes one object from the List and sets several properties. If I use just `Show()` it works properly, but I need modal window so I cannot click in the mainWindow.

Comment: If I understand MVVM correctly, you're supposed to create a Command that does everything you need. So the command should be opening the window and also what your click is currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use BackgroundWorker for this sort of thing to free the UI thread from being blocked by the Dialog.

Here is an example:  http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/112547-using-the-backgroundworker-in-c%23/

Comment: well, in this case I could write method in my ViewModel which performs the same as the command and call it from button_click...if I get it right the backgroundWorker would also be called from button_click.